# Copy a pointer to a static array

Tags: c++, android, java-native-interface, opengl-es-2.0

I'm developing an Android application with some native code (used to render with OpenGL ES 2.0).

I have the following method signature:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_xxxxxx_xxxx_ActivityRenderer_renderFrame
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj,
          jfloatArray vertices, jfloatArray normals,
          jfloatArray texCoord, jintArray indices)
```

To get access to `jfloatArray vertices, jfloatArray normals, jfloatArray texCoord, jintArray indices` elements I do the following:

```
jfloat *vertPos, *vertNorm, *vertTexC;
jint *indicesArray;

vertPos = env->GetFloatArrayElements(vertices, 0);
vertNorm = env->GetFloatArrayElements(normals, 0);
vertTexC = env->GetFloatArrayElements(texCoord, 0);
indicesArray = env->GetIntArrayElements(indices, 0);
```

And, after glDrawElements(...), at the end, I do the following:

```
env->ReleaseFloatArrayElements(vertices, vertPos, 0);
env->ReleaseFloatArrayElements(normals, vertNorm, 0);
env->ReleaseFloatArrayElements(texCoord, vertTexC, 0);
env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(indices, indicesArray, 0);
```

I'm not drawing the model that I want, probably, because I'm releasing pointers while they are still been using by glDrawElements. I'm not sure, but I want to check it before doing any other tests.

My question is how can I make an static array from a pointer?

I can get pointers' elements doing this:

```
jsize numVertices = env->GetArrayLength(vertices);
jsize numNormals = env->GetArrayLength(normals);
jsize numTexCoords = env->GetArrayLength(texCoord);
GLsizei numIndices = (GLsizei) env->GetArrayLength(indices);
```

But I don't know how to continue.

Any advice?

I'm searching the web to find how, and if I find something I will tell you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me know if I'm misinterpreting what you're asking, but it sounds like you need to brush up on your C++.  Static arrays in C++ have a fixed size at compile-time.  You probably want to look into using `new[]`, or `malloc()` to achieve what you want.